# Error: "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" on OSX

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

System Preferences show MySQL is running.  I can log into MySQL in Terminal logging is root.

I have set up a local host at "localhost/~jason/".  Installed phpMyAdmin to "localhost/~jason/phpMyAdmin" which seems to work.  But when I try to log in as root I get "Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

I am running OSX 10.10.3.  MySQL 5.6.25.  phpMyAdmin 4.4.9.

Comment: Have a look at the url you have in your config.inc.php for what address you use to connect to the server. Try localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you!  Thank you!  This worked.  I changed host to 127.0.0.1.  It was set to localhost by default.  Thanks again!

Comment: Will make it an answer and you can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your config.inc.php and try to switch between localhost and 127.0.0.1 to connect to the MySQL server

Comment: Hey there i have the same problem, when i allow nopasswordallowed i can get in but when i set a password and disallow nopasswordallowed i get the same error-message w/o errorcode-

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the right password in config.inc.php? And that you match the right user and password?

Comment: yep! it's my password i'm using for years :)
I'm afraid i made some wrong configurations with the permissions lately.. but as i said allowing access without pw works fine and i can create databases aswell

Comment: @moesphemie try to change the password with a login from the terminal instead of using phpMyadmin. Can I suggest you to post your own question as well so that you can explain your situation, get the proper help and your question can be used as reference from other users?

Comment: When i type php -v it shows me that i'm running php 5.6.10 
thats strange because i setup my local web-environment where all sites are stored in ~/Sites (according to https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) and when i take a look at the phpinfo it shows me that php 5.5.20 is running which i need since i installed mcrypt for magento - could this be the problem??

Comment: please, open your own question. This is not how SO is intended to work! your comments are not related to the OP question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81400/discussion-between-moesphemie-and-lelio-faieta).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried WAMP? It`s much easier and simpler. Only takes a couple of minutes to set up and it has the newest PHP and MySQL versions.

Comment: I'm not on Windows.  Tried XAMPP but had trouble getting it started.

Comment: Try other systems, such as LAMP or MAMP, I would recomend AMPPS. It has the most features compared to others, but it`s quite new and could be unstable.